# CSS width transition without auto

Tags: css, width, css-transitions

I have an issue where my CSS animation is jumping straight from start to end, and the issue seems to be related to the one answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391479/cant-make-css-width-transition-work). My question is this: How can I make a width transition from x pixels to "auto" without actually using the auto keyword?

Comment: and what exactly in this post's accepted answer doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: @JeremyThille I need to have the final width fit the contents of the div. The "auto" keyword is obviously the one to use for this, but as mentioned in that post, you cannot use the auto keyword when transitioning width.

Comment: Yep, I get what you want to achieve. The post you mentioned has an accepted answer that points to a working demo with the whole code, so, what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: @JeremyThille The demo did not address my issue, which was needing to not specify a specific end width. Dennis's solution worked, however. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width auto and a fixed width can't be animated. What you can do is change the max-width.

```
.element{
   max-width: 0;
   width: 0;
   transition: your transition style
}
.element.active{
   max-width: 9999px;
   width: auto;
}
```

I'll hope this helps

Comment: This has perfectly solved my issue! I had to lengthen the transition time a bit, and text wrapping was an issue, but now it works perfect. Thank you!